# mysql2 gem hangs during installation

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu-14.04

I'm using mysql as the database for a rails app and trying to bundle install the `mysql2` gem. During the step

```
Installing mysql2 0.3.19 with native extensions
```

rather than failing and giving me an error message, it simply hangs and never gives any output at all.

For background I'm installing on a fresh digital ocean droplet that comes with rails installed on Ubuntu 14.04, using ruby 2.0.0 and without specifying a version for the `mysql2` gem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like I had the wrong version of mysql installed. Uninstalling all versions of mysql and then running

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev
```

worked for me.

Comment: When I ran this command, it uninstalled already installed mysql 5.6 and installed mysql 5.7. I do not want to install new version of mysql. Any workarounds?

Comment: I suspect you can specify the version that you want? Typically package managers will just install the latest version by default but then let you specify a specific version if you need it. I'd look into that.